# dplyr: how to pivot_wider with multiple columns while creating new covariates at the same time?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot

I have a proteomics dataset currently with ~60 columns (patients and information such as protein names) and ~1800 rows (the specific proteins).

I need to convert from long to wide format so that each row corresponds to the patients while all the columns represent the proteins. I can do (very) simple conversions, but there are many columns in this example and, in extension, some data management is required as new covariates needs to be created/extracted from the raw proteomics output below. I simply does not know how to proceed and have not found any solutions looking at many available walk-throughs of converting large datasets like this.

I prefer `dplyr`-inputs, hints or solutions.

The raw output from the proteomic-software looks something like this:

```
> head(Heat_BT)
# A tibble: 11 x 6
   protein                                        gene   Intensity_10 Intensity_11 Intensity_MB_1 Intensity_Ref1
   <chr>                                          <chr>  <chr>        <chr>        <chr>          <chr>         
 1 NA                                             NA     Bruschi      Bruschi      Reichl         Reichl        
 2 NA                                             NA     Ctrl         Ctrl         Tumor          Ctrl          
 3 NA                                             NA     Hydro        Hydro        Malignant      Hydro         
 4 NA                                             NA     Ctrl         Ctrl         MB             Ctrl          
 5 von Willebrand factor                          VWF    0.674627721  0.255166769  0.970489979    0.215972215   
 6 Sex hormone-binding globulin                   SHBG   0.516914487  0.476843655  0.88173753     0.306484252   
 7 Glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase       GAPDH  0.622163594  0.231107563  0.71856463     0.204625234   
 8 Nestin                                         NES    0.868476391  0.547319174  0.832109928    0.440162212   
 9 Heat shock 70 kDa protein 13                   HSPA13 0.484973907  0.435322136  0.539334834    0.28678757    
10 Isocitrate dehydrogenase [NADP], mitochondrial IDH2   1.017596364  0.107395157  0.710225344    0.251976997   
11 Mannan-binding lectin serine protease 1        MASP1  0.491321206  0.434995681  0.812500775    0.403583705
```

**Expected output:**

```
              id     lab malig      diag       VWF      SHBG     GAPDH       NES    HSPA13      IDH2     MASP1
1   Intensity_10 Bruschi  Ctrl     Hydro 0.6746277 0.5169145 0.6221636 0.8684764 0.4849739 1.0175964 0.4913212
2   Intensity_11 Bruschi  Ctrl     Hydro 0.2551668 0.4768437 0.2311076 0.5473192 0.4353221 0.1073952 0.4349957
3 Intensity_MB_1  Reichl Tumor Malignant 0.9704900 0.8817375 0.7185646 0.8321099 0.5393348 0.7102253 0.8125008
4 Intensity_Ref1  Reichl  Ctrl     Hydro 0.2159722 0.3064843 0.2046252 0.4401622 0.2867876 0.2519770 0.4035837
```

- The proteomic-software automatically prints the first four rows as categories, which each patient belongs to.

Based on these first four rows:

- There must be added four new covariates to the wide format: **(1)** `Heat_BT$id` correspond to the study name of each patient, **(2)** `Heat_BT$lab` correspond to what lab have produced the data, **(3)** `Heat_BT$malig` correspond to whether the patient case is a control case or a tumor case and finally, **(4)** `Heat_BT$diag` correspond to the underlying diagnosis.

**Data**

```
Heat_BT <- structure(list(protein = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "von Willebrand factor", 
                           "Sex hormone-binding globulin", "Glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase", 
                           "Nestin", "Heat shock 70 kDa protein 13", "Isocitrate dehydrogenase [NADP], mitochondrial", 
                           "Mannan-binding lectin serine protease 1"), gene = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                NA, NA, "VWF", "SHBG", "GAPDH", "NES", "HSPA13", "IDH2", "MASP1"
                           ), Intensity_10 = c("Bruschi", "Ctrl", "Hydro", "Ctrl", "0.674627721", 
                                               "0.516914487", "0.622163594", "0.868476391", "0.484973907", "1.017596364", 
                                               "0.491321206"), Intensity_11 = c("Bruschi", "Ctrl", "Hydro", 
                                                                                "Ctrl", "0.255166769", "0.476843655", "0.231107563", "0.547319174", 
                                                                                "0.435322136", "0.107395157", "0.434995681"), Intensity_MB_1 = c("Reichl", 
                                                                                                                                                 "Tumor", "Malignant", "MB", "0.970489979", "0.88173753", "0.71856463", 
                                                                                                                                                 "0.832109928", "0.539334834", "0.710225344", "0.812500775"), 
               Intensity_Ref1 = c("Reichl", "Ctrl", "Hydro", "Ctrl", "0.215972215", 
                                  "0.306484252", "0.204625234", "0.440162212", "0.28678757", 
                                  "0.251976997", "0.403583705")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                     "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution for you. Its two steps, as you would need to collect `intensity`-variables first.

```
Heat_BT <- Heat_BT %>% na.exclude()

Heat_BT[,-1] %>% pivot_longer(
        cols = Intensity_10:Intensity_Ref1,
        names_to = "id"
) %>% pivot_wider(
        names_from = gene
) %>% mutate(
        across(.cols = -"id", as.numeric)
)
```

Which gives the following `output`

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  id             VWF         SHBG        GAPDH       NES         HSPA13      IDH2        MASP1      
  <chr>          <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 Intensity_10   0.674627721 0.516914487 0.622163594 0.868476391 0.484973907 1.017596364 0.491321206
2 Intensity_11   0.255166769 0.476843655 0.231107563 0.547319174 0.435322136 0.107395157 0.434995681
3 Intensity_MB_1 0.970489979 0.88173753  0.71856463  0.832109928 0.539334834 0.710225344 0.812500775
4 Intensity_Ref1 0.215972215 0.306484252 0.204625234 0.440162212 0.28678757  0.251976997 0.403583705
```

I had trouble seeing the connection between the `variables` you wanted to add from the `data`, so I assumed that once you were able to `pivot` you data correctly, you would be able to fill in the rest.

Ill happily revise my answer, if you can explain it more plainly how these variables are related.

Best

**EDIT:** Notice that I removed the first four rows from the `data` as I didnt immediately see the connection between the variables that you wanted added.

**EDIT 2:** I assumed that the first 3 rows are the covariates that you want to add such that the first row is `lab`, `malig` and `diag` respectively.

```
# Extract the relevant information
# from the data.
id_cols <- bind_cols(
        var = c("lab", "malig", "diag"),
        Heat_BT[1:3,-c(1,2)] 
) %>% group_by(var) %>% pivot_longer(
        cols = Intensity_10:Intensity_Ref1, names_to = "id"
) %>% pivot_wider(
        names_from = var,
)
        
        
# Remove these identifiers;
Heat_BT <- Heat_BT %>% na.exclude() 

# Pivot the table;
pivoted_table <- Heat_BT[,-1] %>% pivot_longer(
        cols = Intensity_10:Intensity_Ref1,names_to = "id"
) %>% pivot_wider(
        names_from = gene,
) %>% mutate(
        across(.cols = -"id", as.numeric)
        )

# Join with the ID colums
left_join(
        id_cols,
        pivoted_table
)
```

Which gives the `output`,

```
# A tibble: 4 x 11
  id             lab     malig diag      VWF         SHBG        GAPDH       NES         HSPA13      IDH2        MASP1      
  <chr>          <chr>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 Intensity_10   Bruschi Ctrl  Hydro     0.674627721 0.516914487 0.622163594 0.868476391 0.484973907 1.017596364 0.491321206
2 Intensity_11   Bruschi Ctrl  Hydro     0.255166769 0.476843655 0.231107563 0.547319174 0.435322136 0.107395157 0.434995681
3 Intensity_MB_1 Reichl  Tumor Malignant 0.970489979 0.88173753  0.71856463  0.832109928 0.539334834 0.710225344 0.812500775
4 Intensity_Ref1 Reichl  Ctrl  Hydro     0.215972215 0.306484252 0.204625234 0.440162212 0.28678757  0.251976997 0.403583705
```

This will work with the data that you have, regardless of size. Clearly, you can make the approach more bullet-proof by replacing, for example, `cols = Intensity_10:Intensity_Ref1` to `contains("intensity")`.

**Edit 3**

You have a lot more variables than provided here, so when you `pivot` these are not modified during the `pivot`-process.

So we can take a more robust approach, assuming that all the `variables` not provided here are similar to the ones provided, by changing `cols`-argument accordingly.

```
# Extract the relevant information
# from the data.
id_cols <- bind_cols(
        var = c("lab", "malig", "diag"),
        Heat_BT[1:3,-c(1,2)] 
) %>% group_by(var) %>% pivot_longer(
        cols = -"var", names_to = "id"
) %>% pivot_wider(
        names_from = var,
)


# Remove these identifiers;
Heat_BT <- Heat_BT[-(1:4),]

# Pivot the table;
pivoted_table <- Heat_BT[,-1] %>% pivot_longer(
        cols = -"gene",
        names_to = "id"
) %>% pivot_wider(
        names_from = gene,
) %>% mutate(
        across(.cols = -"id", as.numeric)
)

# Join with the ID colums
left_join(
        id_cols,
        pivoted_table
)
```

Which gives the same output as above.

Comment: Hi @Serkan, thank you very much for this solution. All values in the  **EDIT 2 output** are `as.character`. Is there an easy way to ensure that all values in the output are `as.numeric`?

Comment: You can add `values_fn = as.numeric` in `pivot_wider`, but personally I would do that with `mutate` after you have your desired output!

Comment: My apologies for asking, but could you perhaps update the answer with the `mutate`-approach for converting all `intensity`-columns to `as.numeric()`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My answer is updated! But keep in mind that this approach assumes you remove the `lab`, `diag` and `malig` part of the data first and named the new colum as `id` in `pivot_longer`, as I have done. The reason that Id prefer `mutate` over `values_fn` is that it gives me, at least, a better understanding of the data manipulation approach.

Comment: Thank you for helping its really appreciated. However, I seem to receive this error while using your update: **Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(.cols = -"id", as.numeric)`.
x 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**

Comment: Interesting. Does this error appear in your own data, or does it also appear in the sample data that you provided? Can you test that, please?

Comment: Hm, it only occurs in my dataset and not the data sample provided. Do you have any idea what have causes this issue?

Comment: Yes I have a pretty good idea. In your own data, you have many more `variables`, correct? Are all these variables `numeric`, or is there `date` and `character` too? We can change the approach slightly to mitigate this problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would really appreciate that. I can mail you the .csv file, or would you prefer looking at it here on stackoverflow? All "gene"-columns are loaded as `col_character()`.

Comment: Ill modify my answer, and if that doesn't work we can look at alternative solutions. All the remaining variables are similar to those that you have provided here, yes? They are all supposed to be `numeric` variables, yes?

Comment: Yes, (1) There are the `protein` and `gene` columns which are supposed to be `as.scharacter()` and (2) the rest are intensity-columns, which currently are loaded in as `col_character()` but are supposed to be `as.numeric`. The final output still needs the new columns `lab`, `malig` and `diag`, which you correctly have produced.

Comment: Ok, I modifed my answer. Let me know how it went. Remember the solution assumes that the first four rows are not needed for other than creating `lab`, `malig` and `diag`.

Comment: Really appreciate it - but, (1) running on my dataset still gives **'Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.ℹ `..1 = across(.cols = -"id", as.numeric)`. x 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**. I am also receiving this warning while running the `pivoted_table <- ...`-part - perhaps it has something to do with it? **Warning message: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols. * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning. * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates**

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/serkor/ - lets do this!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
Heat_BT[,2][1:3] <- c('lab', 'malig', 'diag')
data.table::transpose(Heat_BT[,-1],keep.names = 'gene',make.names = TRUE)

            gene     lab malig      diag   NA         VWF        SHBG       GAPDH         NES      HSPA13        IDH2       MASP1
1   Intensity_10 Bruschi  Ctrl     Hydro Ctrl 0.674627721 0.516914487 0.622163594 0.868476391 0.484973907 1.017596364 0.491321206
2   Intensity_11 Bruschi  Ctrl     Hydro Ctrl 0.255166769 0.476843655 0.231107563 0.547319174 0.435322136 0.107395157 0.434995681
3 Intensity_MB_1  Reichl Tumor Malignant   MB 0.970489979  0.88173753  0.71856463 0.832109928 0.539334834 0.710225344 0.812500775
4 Intensity_Ref1  Reichl  Ctrl     Hydro Ctrl 0.215972215 0.306484252 0.204625234 0.440162212  0.28678757 0.251976997 0.403583705
```

Comment: Hi @Onyambu, thank you very much for your input. I receive an error while trying to run your script: `> Heat_BT[,2][1:3] <- c('lab', 'malig', 'diag')` gives this:
**Error: Assigned data `c("lab", "malig", "diag") must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 1811 rows.
x Assigned data has 3 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.** Do you know how this can be fixed?